# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Log analysis

Tags: sql-server-2008, transaction-log

I have a SQL Server 2008 database with a transaction log that grows very rapidly each day. Is anyone aware of any tool that could be used to analyze in greater detail what transactions that make up the greater part of the log bulk? This so I know where to direct my attention.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Best regards
Marcus

Comment: `sys.dm_tran_database_transactions` has some relevant columns. You could poll this but for multi statement transactions I'm not sure if you could automatically tie this back to the individual statement that generated the logging activity.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an analyzer, but [ApexSQL](http://www.apexsql.com) has tools to read log files; the other option is to use Profiler to monitor the activity.

I would also recommend getting to know the tables in the database, take record counts daily and see where your growth is.